# Stop iterating in forEach or another array iteration - do something just for first case (js)

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, loops

I have data that is array of arrays. It is something like:

```
[
  [
    {
      id: 1,
      itemName: 'xxx',
      ...
    },
    {
      id: 1,
      itemName: 'yyy',
      ...
    },
    ...
  ],
  [
    {
      id: 2,
      itemName: 'aaa',
      ...
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      itemName: 'kkk',
      ...
    },
    ...
  ],
  [
    {
      id: 3,
      itemName: 'kkk',
      ...
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      itemName: 'yyy',
      ...
    },
    ...
  ]
]
```

I need to iterate them while looking for itemName and when i find it put its ID as a key to state value (React). The issue is, that itemName can be the same in multiple arrays but  I want to setState **just for the first occurance**. Here is what I have:

```
  const handle = itemId => {
    arrays.forEach(arrItem => {
      arrItem.forEach(item => {
        if (item.itemName === itemId) {
          if (!Object.keys(this.state.cartons).includes(item.id)) {
            this.setState(prevState => ({
              ...prevState,
              cartons: {
                ...prevState.cartons,
                [item.id]: {
                  id: item.id,
                  items: arrItem,
                  itemsFound: [item.itemName],
                },
              },
            }));
          }
        }
      });
    });
  };
```

After calling `handle('yyy')` my cartons from state should be:
{
  1: {
    ...
  }
}
But it is now:

```
{
  1: {
    ...
  }.
  3: {
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: This line is weird : `itemsFound: [itemName]`, what is `itemName` ?

Comment: @Kuo-hsuanHsu my bad, should be item.itemName, updated

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a forEach loop for this. you need to use a standard for loop to "break" out . From the docs:

There is no way to stop or break a forEach() loop other than by throwing an exception. If you need such behavior, the forEach() method is the wrong tool.

Early termination may be accomplished with:

- A simple for loop
- A for...of / for...in loops
- Array.prototype.every()
- Array.prototype.some()
- Array.prototype.find()
- Array.prototype.findIndex()

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

```
const handle = itemId => {
    for(let i = 0; i < arrays.length; i++) {
    let arrItem = arrays[i];
      for(let j = 0; j < arrItem.length; j++) {
        let item = arrItem[j];

        if (item.itemName === itemId) {
          if (!Object.keys(this.state.cartons).includes(item.id)) {
            this.setState(prevState => ({
              ...prevState,
              cartons: {
                ...prevState.cartons,
                [item.id]: {
                  id: item.id,
                  items: arrItem,
                  itemsFound: [itemName],
                },
              },
            }));
          }
        }
      };
    };
  };
```

So use a for loop like above, but add your "break" statement whether it needs to go based upon your logic

Comment: Is it impossible to use any new array iterators like find, some etc instead of classic loops?

Comment: It’s not impossible to use them, depending on what you’re doing. A lot of those are designed to be performed on every item so are more convenient than a standard for. It comes down to knowing the best tool for the job